# Query de pesquisa C# OleDb

Tags: c#, microsoft-access, oledb

No programa em que estou trabalhando, fiz um form de pesquisa de dados, onde o nome digitado será pesquisado no banco de dados e retornará resultados próximos

[image]

(Tela de pesquisa)

O problema é que a query só retornará algum dado caso o que for inserido na textbox for idêntico ao que há registrado no banco

Minha query:

```
private void populate(string name)
    {
        lvPesquisa.Items.Add(new ListViewItem(new[] { name }));
    }

private void pbSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string strConnection = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source="
               + Application.StartupPath + @"\NOME DO BANCO.mdb";

        OleDbConnection dbConnection = new OleDbConnection(strConnection);

        OleDbCommand cmdQry = dbConnection.CreateCommand();

        Nome = txtNome.Text;

        try
        {
            dbConnection.Open();

            OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("SELECT nomeCadastro FROM TABELA WHERE nomeCadastro=? ORDER BY nomeCadastro ASC", dbConnection);
            OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);

            adapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nome", Nome);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            adapter.SelectCommand = cmd;
            adapter.Fill(dt);
            //LOOP THROUGH DATATABLE
            foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
            {
                populate(row[0].ToString());
            }


            //CLEAR DATATABLE
            dt.Rows.Clear();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Erro", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
        finally
        {
            dbConnection.Close();
        }
    }
```

(Nome da tabela e do banco de dados foram retirados - a LISTVIEW se chama lvPesquisa e só há 1 coluna)

Preciso que a query retorne dados parecidos com o digitado na caixa de texto. Alguma ideia? Grato.

Comment: Tente utilizar o operador `LIKE`, o operador `LIKE` é utilizado para buscar por uma determinada `string` dentro de um campo com valores textuais. Com ele podemos, por exemplo, buscar os registros cujo NOME inicia com uma determinada palavra, ou contém um certo texto.

Para efetuar esse tipo de consulta, podemos utilizar também o caractere `%` para indicar um `coringa`, ou seja, um texto qualquer que pode aparecer no campo. Por exemplo:
`SELECT * FROM PESSOA WHERE Nome LIKE '%@nome%'`

Comment: Infelizmente não deu certo. Mas obrigado

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tente colocar o like como sugeriu nosso amigo Albert Da seguinte forma:

```
OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("SELECT nomeCadastro FROM TABELA WHERE 
                                    nomeCadastro like ? ORDER BY nomeCadastro ASC", dbConnection);
        OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);

        adapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@nome", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = "%" + Nome + "%";
```

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente! Muito obrigado.